# Check the quantity in the database every 15 seconds

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, winforms

I want to ask a question, I want to keep tracking the `quantity` in the database every 15 seconds or so.. It works fine, but the problem is it check the every column that have `quantity` less than 5, not single column of `quantity` that have less than 5. I have the database like the image below:

[image]

And from the image below, I minus the Quantity from the below image to the database (above image), so the quantity in the database (above image) is now 2, whenever the Quantity in first and second row (below image) are less than 5, it will show the box in the bottom right corner like the below image:

[image]

The problem is, either the quantity in the first or second row of the database still more than 5 or equal (for example: the quantity in the first row of the database is 2, but in the second row is 50), the box in the bottom right corner like above image does not show, it only shows when the quantity in first and second row in the database less than 5.

My question is: How do I show the box whenever either the quantity in the first or second row more than 5?

Here is the code that I am using:

**System Manager class:**

```
public static void GetQuantity()
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT [Quantity] FROM [Database]";

        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int quantity = (int)reader["Quantity"];

                    UserInformation.Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(quantity);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}

public static void CheckQuantity(CustomToolTip _customToolTip, IWin32Window _window, int _x, int _y, int _duration)
{
    GetQuantity();

    string message = string.Empty;

    string productCode = string.Empty;

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT [ProductCode] FROM [Database] WHERE [Quantity] = @Quantity ORDER BY [ProductCode] ASC";

        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", OleDbType.Decimal);
            command.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = UserInformation.Quantity;

            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    productCode = (string)reader["ProductCode"];

                    if (UserInformation.Quantity < 5)
                    {
                        message += "- Product Code: " + productCode + "\n- Quantity: " + UserInformation.Quantity + "\n\n";
                    }
                }

                if (message != string.Empty)
                {
                    SystemManager.SoundEffect(@"\Media\Speech Off.wav");

                    string _message1 = "The system has detected the following: \n\n";
                    string _message2 = "Have quantity less than 5.\nPlease update them immediately.";

                    if (UserInformation.Language == "Indonesian")
                    {
                        _message1 = "Program mendeteksi bahwa: \n\n";
                        _message2 = "Memiliki kuantitas kurang dari 5.\nPerbarui segera.";
                    }

                    _customToolTip.Show(_message1 + message + _message2, _window, _x, _y, _duration);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**User Information class:**

```
public static decimal Quantity
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

**Main System class:** Here is where I called the box and minus the quantity from this class to the database:

```
int timeLeft = 15;

Timer _timer = new Timer();

void MainSystem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _timer.Interval = 1000;

   _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

   _timer.Start();
}

void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     timeLeft--;

     if (timeLeft == 0)
     {
         _timer.Stop();

         MessageBox.Show("The timer has been stopped");

         SystemManager.GetQuantity();

         if (UserInformation.Quantity < 5)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("The quantity less than 5");

             SystemManager.CheckQuantity(customToolTip1, this, _screen.Right, _screen.Bottom, 5000);

             timeLeft = 15;

             _timer.Start();
         }

         else if (UserInformation.Quantity >= 5)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("The quantity more than 5 or equal");

             timeLeft = 15;

             _timer.Start();
         }

         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Nothing");

             timeLeft = 15;

             _timer.Start();
         }

     }
 }
```

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? It is not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: This topic does not make sense at all. Your title says you have an error, which you don't show in the thread itself and I was unable to follow your intention of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LajosArpad: I have edited the question sir, please let me know if you still not clear about what I am trying to achive. Thank you

Comment: @Samuel: I already mention about what is the error in the question and I already updated the question sir, please let me know if you still not clear about what I am trying to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    int quantity = (int)reader["Quantity"];

    UserInformation.Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(quantity);
}
```

you are overwriting the value of `UserInformation.Quantity` over and over until the last row, and it keeps whatever value is in the last row.

You haven't shown us how your `UserInformation` class is defined, so it's hard to show you how to modify it, but basically, you should only be querying for rows that are applicable:

```
string query = "SELECT [Product Code], [Quantity] FROM [Database] " +
               "WHERE [Quantity] < 5";
```

Build up a list of the results:

```
var lowProducts = new List<ProductInfo>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int quantity = (int)reader["Quantity"];
    string code = (string)reader["Product Code"];

    lowProducts.Add(new ProductInfo(code, quantity));    
}

UserInformation.LowProducts = lowProducts;
```

And then you can check whether `LowProducts` has any items in it:

```
if (UserInformation.LowProducts.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some products are running low.");

    SystemManager.CheckQuantity(customToolTip1, this, _screen.Right,
                               _screen.Bottom, 5000);
    timeLeft = 15;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

**Edit:** to answer your question in the comments, one simple way you could implement `ProductInfo` is:

```
class ProductInfo
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }

    public ProductInfo(string code, int quantity)
    {
        Code = code;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir @JLRishe, but what is the `UserInformation.LowProducts?`. I don't seems to find `.Any()` while I was make getter and setter of `UserInformation.LowProducts` to be `decimal`. Thank you. And what is the `ProductInfo sir? What data contains in it? Thank you very much

Comment: @UnknownUser LowProducts would be an `IEnumerable<ProductInfo>` (`ProductInfo` is a class for holding product info). Since there can be more than one product with low quantity, you need to get _all_ of them, not just one. Just storing one product in UserInformation.Quantity is the whole source of your problem.

Comment: Hi sir, I am still confusing about what to do on `ProductInfo` class, so I made it like this, can you help me again sir? I have uploaded the code for this problem to dropbox, i will share the link to you. Please have a look at it and help me once more sir. Thank you very much. Here is the link: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5zw1z3tzat12ts/New%20Text%20Document.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @UnknownUser Please see my revision above.

Comment: Hi sir, I have discover a new problem. Suppose there are two datas in the database with different `Quantity`, the first one is 2 and the second one is 3.. The message will show the lowest `Quantity` of the datas in the database, not both of that (because the `Quantity` for both of it less than 5). I have posted a new question instead sir. If I did not bother you with this, please have a look sir: [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693169/quantity-tracking-in-the-database)